# Plot Nusselt number between two plates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, computational-physics, flow, convection

I have a free convection system between two walls (hot, and cold). And I have the temperature distribution between them, solved numerically. Now I need to plot the Nusselt number between walls.

This figure describes the system:

[image]

Where **back**, **front**, **top**, **bottom** walls are, adiabatic. And is a 3D steady-state case. Then I have the numerical solution for the temperature distribution of the inner volume between the walls. What I want is to plot the Nusselt number over a vector normal to that walls. the volume between walls contains a fluid in a free convention state

As far as I know the Nusselt can be computed as

\begin{equation}
   Nu = \frac{hL}{k}
\end{equation}

with

\begin{equation}
   \frac{h}{k} = \frac{\partial (T_h - T)/\partial y}{T_h-T_c}
\end{equation}

Then my question is, if is correct that I can solve the $\frac{h}{k}$ as this equation, where $i$ is a point of that temperature distribution:

\begin{equation}
   \frac{h_i}{k} = \frac{(T_h - T_i)/y_i}{T_h-T_c}
\end{equation}

Then $Nu$ will be:

\begin{equation}
   Nu_i = \frac{h_i L}{k}
\end{equation}

Comment: What is the equation for the heat flux at the bottom plate?

Comment: @ChetMiller, is a steady-state problem so simply $q=h\Delta T$

Comment: Is it correct to say that, except at the bottom and top, the temperature varies with horizontal position?  This is a steady state 3D heat transfer situation, correct?

Comment: @ChetMiller, I update the post to clarify the situation. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this situation correctly, at all depths except at the very top and the very bottom of the gap, energy is transported vertically by both convection and by conduction.  However, due to the non-slip boundary condition, at the very tope ad the very bottom, the fluid velocity is zero, and only conduction is present.  So these are the locations where one can more easily calculate the rate of heat flow.

At the very bottom, the rate of heat flow per unit area is given by $$q=-k\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}\right)_{y=0}$$If we integrate this over the entire area of the base, we obtain:  $$Q=hA(T_h-T_c)=\int_A{-k\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}\right)_{y=0}dA\tag{1}}$$If we define the dimensionless temperature and dimensionless vertical coordinate as $T^*=((T-T_c)/(T_h-T_c)$ and $y^*=y/L$ (where L is the height of the gap), respectively, Eqn. 1 reduces to $$Nu=\frac{hL}{k}=-\frac{1}{A}\int_A{\left(\frac{\partial T^*}{\partial y^*}\right)_{y^*=0}dA}\tag{2}$$So the Nusselt number is basically the magnitude of the vertical dimensionless temperature gradient averaged over the heat transfer surface.

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation of the Nusselt definition, but, then If I solve that integral I will have the Nusselt number that "describe¨ that system. But If I need to plot it $\partial T/\partial y$ can be computed as $\Delta T/\Delta y$ along the path from one surface to another.

Comment: Oh.  I thought the two plates were horizontal.  But, the same principles apply.  Unless H and D are much larger than W, the convective flow is 3D throughout the chamber.  Of course, in the limit where  H and D actually are  infinite relative to W (i.e., two infinite parallel vertical plates), the flow becomes 1D, with the velocity vector upward in the half-channel near the hot wall and downward in the half-channel near the cold wall.  Only under these circumstances is your approach valid.

Comment: The solution to this  problem for infinite   parallel plates is given in Transport Phenomena by Bird et al, Section 10.9.  To a first approximation, the temperature profile is linear.